# ggplot2 mapping county boundries in one color and state boundries in another on the same map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a choropleth county map with grey borders, and I also want to include the state boundries in black. Does anyone know how I go about adding a second layer of state mapping to an existing county map?

Here's the [data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgD_Tz-IfrD7dFc0d0kxTkJUaWMyUzVub25RS3ZrVXc#gid=0) and code I ended up using:

```
#load libraries
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggmap)
    library(maps)
    library(plyr)

#get wif file
wip <- read.csv("wip.csv") 

#get map data for US counties and states
county_map <- map_data("county")
state_map <- map_data("state")

#merge wip and county_map
wip_map <- merge(county_map, wip, by.x=c("region", "subregion"), 
    by.y=c("region","subregion"), all.x=TRUE)

#resort merged data
wip_map <- arrange(wip_map, group, order)

#relpace NA with 0's
wip_map[is.na(wip_map)] <- 0

#generate a disctrete color pallette    
pal <- c("#F7FCF5","#74C476","#41AB5D","#238B45","#006D2C","#00441B")


theme_clean <- function(base_size = 12) {
    require(grid)
    theme_grey(base_size) %+replace%
    theme(
        axis.title      =   element_blank(),
        axis.text       =   element_blank(),
        panel.background    =   element_blank(),
        panel.grid      =   element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length   =   unit(0,"cm"),
        axis.ticks.margin   =   unit(0,"cm"),
        panel.margin    =   unit(0,"lines"),
        plot.margin     =   unit(c(0,0,0,0),"lines"),
        complete = TRUE
        )
    }

final_map <- ggplot(wip_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=factor(CATEGORY))) +
            geom_polygon(colour="grey", aes(fill=factor(CATEGORY))) +
            scale_fill_manual(values=pal) +
            expand_limits(x = wip_map$long, y = wip_map$lat) +
            coord_map("polyconic") + 
            labs(fill="Number Per\nCounty") + 
                theme_clean()

 final_map + geom_path( data = state_map , colour = "red")
```

Thanks!

Comment: The file that you link for your data set is in your Google Drive trash.  It will disappear soon.  Possible for you to update the content to a more permanent link hosted on something like pastebin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add a `geom_path` to your code...

I used red to highlight the boundaries but you can easily just set it to black.

```
    ggplot( wip_map, aes( x = long , y = lat , group=group ) ) +
        geom_polygon( colour = "grey" , aes( fill = factor( CATEGORY ) ) ) +
        scale_fill_manual( values = pal ) +
        expand_limits( x = wip_map$long, y = wip_map$lat ) +
        coord_map( "polyconic" ) + 
        labs(fill="Number Per\nCounty") + 
        theme_clean( ) +
        geom_path( data = state_map , colour = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, I really a appreciate it. The solution you provided doesn't not seem to work with the code I ended up writing. When I add it to the code below I get the error "Error in factor(CATEGORY) : object 'CATEGORY' not found": `ggplot(wip_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=factor(CATEGORY))) +
 geom_polygon(colour="grey", ) +
 scale_fill_manual(values=pal) +
 expand_limits(x = county_map$long, y = county_map$lat) +
 coord_map("polyconic") + 
 labs(fill="Reps Per\nCounty"`

Comment: Yes, `CATEGORY` is a column name in wip_map, it's indicating which bucket the specific county falls in. I removed the extra comma in `geom_polygon(colour="grey", )` and received the same error. Thanks again.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested above and I  am still getting the error. If you have time to look at the data set and code, it would be very much appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the code above to include `geom_path( data = state_map , colour = "red")`. If you run it, you will get the error ("Error in factor(CATEGORY) : object 'CATEGORY' not found":). Am I adding this in incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: @huxley I have added updated code for you to copy and paste. The problem was you were setting the fill aesthetic in the call to `ggplot` and then also setting it in the call to `geom_polygon`. You only need to do it in `geom_polygon` if you haven't already set the fill aesthetic in the `ggplot` call. HTH.

Comment: It must be a mistake in my code. Your code works great. Thank you so much for bearing with me.

Comment: @huxley no probs. if this solved your problem you should consider accepting the answer by clicking the little green tick box next to my answer. This will mark the question as answered so it will no longer appear on the unanswered questions stack (and you and I get bonus points for it). But you are not under any obligation to do so. Cheers!